How to disable accidental trackpad input in newer silicon M1/M2/M3 macOS Sonoma?
I know we have an old thread on the Apple SE site about this, but none of the posted solutions work on the newer Apple silicon (M1/M2/M3) Macs running macOS Sonoma.
I have tested Karabiner-Multitouch-Extension but sadly it don't work, yet.

Does anyone know a solution for this? It would be a life saver for me because I have multiple sclerosis disease and need to be able to use a external keyboard
and external touchpad in the middle. (No mouse is possible to use).
